# Webpack-dev-server watching specific folder, on file change triggers plugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have folder with `html` files, which compiling by `myHtmlPlugin`. I want `webpack-dev-server` to watch for changes in this folder and run `myHtmlPlugin`. Basically, I want to add watcher without entry point for custom plugin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. All `html` files was compiled to single `js`

```
fs.readdir(directoryPath, (err, files) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/htmltemplates.min.js'),
    this.filecontent,
    (err) => {
      if(err) throw new Error(err);
    }
  )
});
```

2. This output was set as entry point:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    htmlTemplates: 'htmltemplates.min.js',
  },
```

3. Inside plugin class, in Webpack default `apply` method was set watcher:

```
class myHtmlPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    fs.watch(
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates/views/'),
      'utf8', 
      (eventType, filename) => {
          this.compileHtml();
    });
  }
}
```

On file change inside directory, `nodejs` compiling all `html` files to single one, which is entryPoint of `webpack` server.